# How to take a webview screenshot of a particular area in android?

Tags: android, screenshot

I created a application which loads a `webview` inside the app. Its a `POS` application (Web application) loads inside the `webview`. But when a receipt in generated, I want to take the screenshot of the `receipt`. But not the whole page. only that particular container that holds in `receipt`. How could I achieve that? any Suggestion? My intention is to print `receipt`  by taking the screenshot saving in device and printing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can export needed `div` or whatever contains a receipt setting its and its children' css to actually used values (see [Extract the current DOM and print it as a string, with styles intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209161/extract-the-current-dom-and-print-it-as-a-string-with-styles-intact)).

Then you can just output the element to another WebView for printing.

Comment: How could i export this div contents to my android code?

Comment: Look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Comment: The problem is that i could not edit the server codes! Without editing server codes is there any ways! Completely from android application

Comment: You don't need to edit server codes, you can execute javascript on the webpage locally and get html out of it.

Comment: Yes i tried that! Using `  webView.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                        "(document.getElementsByClassname('pos-center-align')[0].innerHTML);");`

Comment: But this works in page reloads! But in POS page URL doesnt change on navigation! Url remains same! Everything works like jquery pages! Even if internet is off this page works