# problem in reading css files in vuejs production from method

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

in vue I have method to read stylesheet files

```
    let stylesHtml = '';
     for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]) {
        stylesHtml += node.outerHTML;
     }
```

it work in local but fails in productions
I need it to print dev content with style

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: it just show print window without style

Comment: If you run `document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')` in the console on your production env, does it work?

Comment: it grab only part of css code, differ from local env

Comment: I think it related to how vuejs build chunk and app css files, but have know idea in how to solved

Comment: to solve it for now I added inline style in print window, I hop someone could explain

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with something like this , so i always tried to get elements by their classes since i create different various css classes . this also makes me reach any desired element , easily and without any problem . like:

```
<div class="cssClass" > .... </div>
.
.
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cssClass");
```

This can make your code to also look cleaner and easier to read .

Comment: but I wont to get style links ( css files ) to add it to print page

Comment: Okay so i can refer you to these . I think you can find your solution there.   
                                                     
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209161/extract-the-current-dom-and-print-it-as-a-string-with-styles-intact                                                                                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867005/extracting-only-the-css-used-in-a-specific-page